# How to publish zip file using npm publish?

Tags: npm, artifactory, npm-publish

I am currently publishing my project to an artifactory registry as a .tgz file. I am working on implementing a CD step that will pull the file from artifactory and put it into an in-house application.

Unfortunately the application only accepts zip files. Is there a way I can specify the format of the file that `npm publish` puts my application in before sending it to my artifactory registry? I don't see any options for this in the documentation, but it seems like it should be possible unless I'm missing something.

Comment: `npm pack` creates the `.tgz`, it should be easy to script unpacking that and zipping the result to a `.zip`. You can't change what `npm publish` does though, as far as I'm aware; it expects a tarball per https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/publish.html.